# Sharepoint Online ClinetContext.ExecuteQuery causes connection reset

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, connection-reset, clientcontext

I have an ASP.NET application hosted in IIS calling Sharepoint using `ClientContext`. On a production deployment, a call to `ExecuteQuery` causes the ASP.NET to throw `net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`. On the server, the following exception was thrown:

```
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponseStream(Stream responseStream)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponse()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.<ExecuteQueryToServerAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
   Cannot complete this action. Please try again.
```

There is no other trace of any other error, except this.

I have tried setting TLS1.2 with no success.

I have also tried using a delay before the call to `ExecuteQuery` and the result was still a failure.

Can anyone suggest what could be going wrong here?

Note: it works perfectly on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

After spending a few valuable hours, I found the solution. One of the fields had a wrong date time value and `Sharepoint`, on the flip side, without throwing a meaningful exception, just caused the request in IIS to abruptly close.